# How to change color on item in Navigation Drawer Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

How to make a item "Our Contacts" a white color?(image below)
[Current Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lnC5.png)

I have a code below, it`s a project template from Android Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my activity_main_drawer xml menu file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group>
        <item android:title="@string/about_toefl"
            android:id="@+id/menu_nav_about_toefl"/>
        <item android:title="@string/about_toefl"
            android:id="@+id/menu_nav_the_toefl_itp_tests"/>
        <item android:title="@string/about_toefl"
            android:id="@+id/menu_nav_the_toefl_itp_digital_tests"/>
        <item android:title="@string/about_toefl"
            android:id="@+id/menu_nav_contact_us"/>
        <item android:title="@string/about_toefl"
            android:id="@+id/menu_nav_about_us"/>
    </group>
    <group>
        <item android:title="@string/our_contacts">
            <menu>
                <item android:title="@string/toefl_ucok_org_kz"/>
                <item android:title="@string/phone_7_747_857_97_61"/>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

this is created with a project template
thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have menu item like this -->

```
<item android:title="Tools"
   android:id="@+id/tools">
    <menu>
        <item="@+i
               ...........
         />
    </menu>
</item>
```

`styles.xml`

```
<style name="changecolor">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity.java

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

    MenuItem tools= menu.findItem(R.id.tools);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(tools.getTitle());
    s.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.changecolor), 0, s.length(), 0);
    tools.setTitle(s);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

**OR**

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.titleColor"
..>
```

style:--

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.titleColor" parent="">
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: I added a menu file, please check it =)